# Bell Numbers algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm for finding out the number of ways n numbers can be ordered. For example, two number say a and b can be ordered in 3 ways..

Similarly, 3 numbers can be arranged in 13 ways.

I found out that I can solve the problem using dynamic programming. And here's is what I'm thinking to have layers which represent different ordering. Ex. `a > b` have two layers and `a = b` has a single layer and so on. So that I can use it for later purposes as done in dynamic programming. But I'm not able to write a recurrence relation for the same. Can someone suggest me how can I write that?

Comment: Can you explain the problem some more? Maybe copy the original assignment?

Comment: These are known as the ordered Bell numbers. You can look up sequence A000670 in the OEIS for many references and formulae for computing the sequence.

Comment: Are you trying to simply determine the number of orderings, or generate the orderings themselves?

Comment: @Iridium- Just the ordering..

Comment: I gave up on my solution after many (enjoyable) hours.  I tried a variety of approaches to get a closed-form formula for the number.  The most fruitful was a combinatorial partitioning into chains of equalities and inequalities, but I had a problem counting the sets of equivalent solutions emitted by the symmetric property of equality.  I can send my work to anyone who emails me for it.

Comment: @Nabb: Doh! I just browsed the article on Bell numbers.  I was trying to partition with the equality sub-sequences, my problems go away if I partition with the inequalities.  Oh well, learned something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume f(n,k) = number of possible ways by having k inequality (and so n-k-1 equality), so:
assume you have n-1 number, now you want to add another number and calculate f(n,k), then we have two possibility:

1) There are (k-1) inequalities in those (n-1) numbers, and there are (k+1)(f(n-1,k-1)) ways to add n'th number so that new inequality added.

2) There are k inequalities in those (n-1) numbers, and there are (k+1)(f(n-1,k)) ways to add n'th number with no additional inequality.

```
f(n,k) = (k+1)(f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k))
```

and what you want is sum of them (from zero to n-1), Bellow code is in c# (just tested for simple cases), in fact We just calculate number of possible ways not generating all ways..

```cs
class EqualInequalPermutation
{
    public int OrderingsNumber(int n)
    {
        int[][] f = new int[n+1][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
        {
            f[i] = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                f[i][j] = 0;
        }
        f[1][0] = 1;
        int factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f[i][0] = 1;
            factorial *= i;
            f[i][i - 1] = factorial;
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                f[i][k] = (k + 1) * (f[i - 1][k - 1] + f[i - 1][k]);
            }
        }
        int answer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            answer += f[n][i];
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the recurrence I was looking for.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) is a great resource for problems like this.  You've given enough information to get the answer too.  Clearly for the degenerate case of zero numbers, only one ordering is possible.  Also only one order exists for a single number.  For two, you said there are three orderings and for three integers there are thirteen.  Search for 1,1,3,13 and the first match that pops up is [this one](http://oeis.org/A000670), "Number of ways n competitors can rank in a competition, allowing for the possibility of ties."  From there you'll see the first twenty or so results in this sequence, and as much content as people have contributed on the sequence.  Listed among others is a recursive solution in Mathematica (reformatted and expanded here for clarification):

```
f[0] = 1
f[1] = 1
f[n_] := f[n] = Sum[ Binomial[n,k] * f[n-k], {k,1,n}]   (* memoizes the values *)
```

that you could implement easily in another language if you prefer.

Hope this helps and that you find the OEIS useful in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Since I randomly passed by this problem but couldn't find simple python implementation in search results. For future reference, below provides python version simple implementation.

Although we can get more comprehensive math proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2469684). Below code will simply follow the formula provided by @Saeed Amiri:

`f(n,k) = (k+1)(f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k))`

```py
def bell_number(num: int) -> int:
    dp = [[0] * num for _ in range(num)]
    dp[0][0] = 1
    for n in range(1, num):
        for k in range(num):
            dp[n][k] = (k+1) * (dp[n-1][k-1] + dp[n-1][k])
    return sum(dp[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is the C++ version of the Same Code  
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n + 1, vector<int>(n + 1, 0));
    dp[1][0] = 1;
    int f = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        dp[i][0] = 1;
        f = f * i;
        dp[i][i - 1] = f;
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
            dp[i][j] = (j + 1) * (dp[i - 1][j - 1] + dp[i - 1][j]);
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ans += dp[n][i];
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```

You can keep taking modulo further, because the answers will increase exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think, that solving it via dynamic programming is like killing the ant with a machinegun.

You definitely should use combinatorics, because it should not be so difficult.

When there is not equality, its `n!` (permutation), then you must count combinations (all equal n-tuples), so its for 3

> 3! + 2*(3 over 2) + (3 over 3) = 13

Answer (score 0):

The following C# program outputs both the number of orderings, and the orderings themselves:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Missing argument - the number of items");
        return;
    }
    int n;
    if (!int.TryParse(args[0], out n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not parse number of items");
        return;
    }
    if (n < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of items must not be negative");
        return;
    }
    var count = GetOrderings(n);
    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", count);
}

private static int GetOrderings(int n)
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => (char)('a' + i)).ToList();
    // Produce distinct orderings of the input items
    return GetOrderings(new List<char>(), items);
}

private static int GetOrderings(List<char> current, List<char> items)
{
    // If we have a complete permutation in current, produce the possible arrangements of signs between them
    if (items.Count == 0) return GetSigns(new List<char>(), current, 0);
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        // nextCurrent = current + i'th element of items
        var nextCurrent = new List<char>(current) { items[i] };
        // nextItems = items excluding the i'th element
        var nextItems = new List<char>(items.Where((c, n) => n != i));
        result += GetOrderings(nextCurrent, nextItems);
    }
    return result;
}

private static int GetSigns(List<char> signs, List<char> items, int n)
{
    if (signs.Count >= items.Count - 1)
    {
        // Once we have sufficient signs, write out the items interleaved with them
        var str = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) str += signs[i - 1];
            str += items[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        return 1;
    }
    var result = GetSigns(new List<char>(signs) { '<' }, items, n + 1);
    // To prevent duplicate orderings, only allow "=" between two items if they are in lexicographic order
    // (i.e. allow "a = b" but not "b = a")
    if (items[n] >= items[n + 1]) return result;
    return result + GetSigns(new List<char>(signs) { '=' }, items, n + 1);
}
```

Example output (for n = 3):

```
a<b<c
a<b=c
a=b<c
a=b=c
a<c<b
a=c<b
b<a<c
b<a=c
b<c<a
b=c<a
c<a<b
c<a=b
c<b<a
Total: 13
```

Comment: Interesting, but it would be nice to have this in closed form.  It would take awhile to run this for large n.  Also, I'm not sure that we can assume lexicographic order on the elements, they could, for example, physical objects being ordered.  Being this is stackoverflow, you're probably safe.  :-)

Comment: The lexicographic order applies only to the *names* of the items (here: a, b, c, etc.) what those names refer to, and any orderings upon them is irrelevant. A rather more compact alternative using Stirling numbers of the second kind is: NumOrderings(n) = Sum[x! * StirlingS2[n, x], x=0..n].

Comment: Thanks Iridium for the code, it works fine. But I was looking for  a recurrence relation.